# Logstash filter section

Tags: filter, logstash, zabbix

Could you please advise how to filter a specific words  with Logstash 1.5? For example, it's necessary to filter the following words: Critical, Exit, Not connected. 
As I remember, in previous versions of Logstash (i.e 1.4 and earlier) it has been possible with **grep** filter.

Currently my logstash.conf contains:

```
input {
file {
    path => ["C:\ExportQ\export.log"]
    type => "Exporter-log"
    codec => plain {
        charset => "CP1251"
    }
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "C:\Progra~1\logstash\sincedb"
    }
}

filter {
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    zabbix {
        zabbix_host => "VS-EXP"
        zabbix_key => "log.exp"
        zabbix_server_host => "192.168.1.71"
        zabbix_value => "message"
    }
}
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a conditional and the drop filter to delete matching messages.

```
filter {
  # Simple substring condition
  if "boring" in [message] {
    drop { }
  }

  # Regexp match
  if [message] =~ /boring/ {
    drop { }
  }
}
```

Comment: Magnus, thanks for reply! But any string, which contains the keywords (Critical, Exit, Not connected), must be send to output (zabbix plugin). All other  messages may be skipped/dropped. Can I use in this situation: if [message] !~ /Error|Critical/ ?

Comment: Yes, just negate the conditions.